# flask JavaScript simple ajax request

Tags: ajax, flask, request

Everything is in the title, I have one button and near from him one text which is write "default" at start. When someone clicks on the button I would like to send "did you receive?" with ajax JavaScript request end the server.py answer "yes".

My server.py:

```
#! /usr/bin/python            
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-               

from flask import Flask, json, request, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def get_data():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = json.loads(request.form.get('data'))
        ss = data['messageClient']
        return str(ss)
    return render_template('test.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

My test.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="UID_boutonTest" onclick="functionTest()" style='left:50px;height:50px;width:200px;'>boutonTest</button>
        <span id="UID_afficheTest" style='text-align: center;'>defaut</span>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          function functionTest()
          {
          alert("click bouton");
            $.ajax(
            {
              type : 'POST',
              url : "/",
              dataType:'json',
              data    : JSON.stringify( { "message" : "didyoureceive?" } ),
              success : function(data)
              {
                if (data !=null)
                {
                  messageServer=data;
                  $('#UID_afficheTest').val(messageServer);
                  document.getElementById('UID_afficheTest').innerHTML = messageServer;
                  alert("messageServer = "+messageServer);
                }
              }/*success : function() {}*/
            });/*$.ajax*/
          }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: tanks for your help you don't imagine how i'm in trouble.
So there is no error, if i click to the button there is the first alert "click bouton" but nothing arrive in the server.py so nothing return in the function success

Comment: put    contentType: "application/json" in your ajax call also. can you see your browser network tab,what is the request ?

Comment: Thanks again to your help (i'm sorry for my english i'm french)
I added contentType: "application/json" in my ajax request.
But you're right, if i use firebug, i go to the network and there is no request when i click to the button.

Comment: did you get "click bouton" alert when you click on button?

Comment: yes This part works so may be my ajax request is wrong?

Comment: is your URL correct?

Comment: yes i think check my server.py it's "@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])"
And i use in my webbrowser "http://localhost:5000/"

Comment: is the python service hosted at your local,and what is the port?

Comment: python3.4 server.py 
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
 * Restarting with reloader
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Feb/2015 14:20:00] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Comment: so is it working now?

Comment: Change your url to "http://127.0.0.1:5000/"

Comment: no it's the same 127.0.0.1 or localhost
I don't understand why my javascript don't send the ajax request

Comment: ok i solved the first problem, i have to put javascript before my html code (maybe cause of latence)
So now my ajax request is good but not the answer, but i have problems in my server i gone debug i come back if i need help
Thank's a lot

Answer (score 0):

Ok so now my ajax request works and the server.py return the good value (if i inspect with firebug i see : ask : "did you reveive" and answer : "I received : did you received" so it works but,
My text doesn't change and i don't understant why my javascript alert doesn't appear (the alert1 and 4 work not the others)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
          function functionTest()
          {
          alert("alert1:click bouton");
            $.ajax(
            {
              type : 'POST',
              url : "/lolo",
              contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
              dataType:'json',
              data    : JSON.stringify( { "messageClient" : "didyoureceive?" } ),
              success : function(data)
              {
                alert("alert2:messageServer = "+data);
                if (data !=null)
                {
                  alert("alert3:messageServer = "+data);
                  messageServer=data;
                  $('#UID_afficheTest').val(messageServer);
                  document.getElementById('UID_afficheTest').innerHTML = messageServer;

                }
              }/*success : function() {}*/
            });/*$.ajax*/
          alert("alert4:after ajax request");
          }
        </script>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="UID_boutonTest" onclick="functionTest()" style='left:50px;height:50px;width:200px;'>boutonTest</button>
        <span id="UID_afficheTest" style='text-align: center;'>defaut</span>

    </body>
</html>
```

and my server :

```
#! /usr/bin/python                                                                        
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-                                                                    

from flask import Flask, json, request, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/lolo", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def get_data():
    if request.method == 'POST':                                  
        data = json.loads(request.data)
        ss = data['messageClient']
        ss = "I received : " + ss
        return str(ss)
    return render_template('test.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: ^^ i'm stupid if i specified dataType:'json',
I have to return : return jsonify(reponseServer=ss)